# How to show only objects those are not selected in Django admin panel referred by Foreign Key?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

In the article, when I add some product, it should not show again while adding a second one. Is there any way to do it?

I have the following models :

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)

class ArticleProduct(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('article', 'product')

    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In admin.py :

```
class ArticleProductIngredientInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = ArticleProduct
    autocomplete_fields = ['product']
    extra = 0

class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ArticleProductIngredientInline]
    search_fields = ['category', ]

    class Meta:
        model = Article

@admin.register(ArticleProduct)
class ArticleProductAdminModel(admin.ModelAdmin):
    autocomplete_fields = ['product', 'article']


class ProductAdminModel(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['product', ]


admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdminModel)
admin.site.register(Article, ArticleAdmin)
```

[image]

I have set the Article and Product field unique in ArticleProudct Model. In the Article model Even if have selected Product 1, while adding second or third products, the first product not be displayed as it is already selected.

Comment: i dont really understand the question here, what do u want to acheive?

Comment: I have added image and some brief about my problem.. Please check and help

Comment: hmm, i don't think that may be possible in the admin section, you could just make you own frontend to have more flexibility and power.